# Best render function in vue 3 script setup

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to mimic the `<component>` component behavior in vue 3 using composition API and script setup in various ways. Here is the first attempt:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {type Component, h, useSlots} from "vue";

const props=defineProps<{is:Component|string,name:string}>()
const slots=useSlots()
// @ts-ignore
const render=h(props.is,{name:props.name},slots)
</script>
<template>
  <render/>
</template>
```

It works well, and I can see in the devtool that the "is" component passed as prop is a direct child of the wrapper component. The attrs are passed to the underlying "is" component and it is reactive to attrs change. But it isn't reactive on props change: A change of the name prop is not taken into account.
I fix it by adding a computed:

```
const render=computed(()=>h(props.is,{name:props.name},slots))
```

Works like a charm like it but maybe there is to much call to the h function and I am afraid that all the v-node hierarchy will maybe be recomputed each time there is a change. And so maybe vue will loose time reconciliating the v-node and the Dom?

So I tryed:

```
const render=()=>h(props.is,{name:props.name},slots)
```

OK but the attrs are not passed to the underlying "is" component.
So last I did:

```
const attrs=useAttrs()
render=()=>h(props.is,mergeProps(attrs,{name:props.name}),slots)
```

Works perfectly but I can see in the devtool that the resulting hierarchy is more complicated: The Wrapper has a child "Render" component which in turn has the underlying "is" component as a child.

So do you have an idea of what is the best between the "computed" and the "mergeProps" solution in terms of performance? It looks like the "mergeProps" is replicating the vue internal merge of attrs and props, not very efficient... But maybe the rendering is faster because the entire v-node is not recreated on each change? (but maybe it is recomputed entirely also?).